# Some basic definitions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $f,g$ be algebraic affine curves in $A_{k}^2$.

1) What does $f,g$ algebraic mean?

I know that a set is algebraic if it is equal to $V(I)$ for some ideal $I$ of the polynomials ring but I don't know what it means for functions.

2) Define the multiplicity of $f$ at $p$ and the interesction multiplicity of $f,g$ at $p$

3) What is meant by the notation $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_k^2,O}$

Thanks

Comment: 1) just means they're polynomials, 2) is slightly more complicated, but assuming some mild things, it probably means the length of $\mathcal{O}_p/(f,g)$ as an $\mathcal{O}_p$-module 3) this is just the local ring of $\mathbb{A}^2$ at the origin--it is just $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$.

Comment: Dear user, you are asking about basic definitions and concepts of introductory algebraic geometry. This site is not meant for that: you should read your notes or some introductory book. Browsing the site will tell you which books are most suitable for you. Good luck!